# Java Error - Cannot find symbol "a"?

Tags: java

For java and as a beginner, for some reason the code I am working on tells me that that it cannot find the symbol 'a' in any of the locations below?

Please can someone help? Thank you.

```
class Numbers
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    for ( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
        a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        System.out.print(a);
        int b = (a*a);  
        int c = (a*a*a);
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(c);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `a` before you assign to it, just like you declared `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 3):

You assign a value to variable `a` but you did not declare the variable.
Write

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]); replace with
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```